# Side effect of merging bad account with good account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, post-ban, merge-accounts

This question is already answered here [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) **but** I have a slightly different from this one.

One of my accounts in Stack Overflow was blocked from answering or posting questions, so I created another *and have been doing good from this new account*.

**My question is**: if I merge that blocked privilege account to my present good account, what effects is my good account going to suffer, for e.g, will this new account (*good account I mean*) be blocked again from posting answers or asking questions, or will I see some other modifications?

**Why am I asking this?** Because I just need 1 account, so another acceptable (but less preferable) solution is to delete that bad account. So unless there are any *side-effects*, I would prefer to merge these good and bad accounts.

Comment: The result will most likely be an evaluation of the banning algorithm run on the merged result. That might see you banned again. But then again, you might be suspended as well for circumventing a ban like that.

Comment: ok but, the word `most likely` creates a doubt in mind whether to merge or not(*not merge is dominant*)....any concrete solution, anyone....from community??

Comment: Just unban the old account, then ask for forgiveness while asking for the merge. Light seven black candles before asking and continuously replace them if they run out. God bless your soul if one of the candles runs out while a moderator is processing your request.

Comment: @JanDvorak : hahahaha....couldn't stop laughing....are u stalking my activities ever since i asked u to vote to open my question??? :p

Comment: Not really. Someone must have been steering my path to make me see this question. In fact, I was not even touching my mouse when this question appeared on my screen.